# returning daily report of user who've parks their scooter within 100m boundary of each location in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am using 2 dataframes.

rent_aug_df looks like:

```
    end_time                lng        lat
0   2019-08-01 05:16:12  127.048667  37.504856
1   2019-08-01 05:39:18  126.934945  37.558505
2   2019-08-01 05:39:47  126.889154  37.581799
3   2019-08-01 05:44:03  0.000000    0.000000
4   2019-08-01 06:00:13  127.067109  37.543945
```

cu_nodes_df looks like:

```
id  title            created_at              lng      lat
0   location_1  2019-01-16 21:21:11     127.03338   37.486277
1   location_2  2019-02-15 20:54:59     127.11021   37.402250
2   location_3  2019-02-22 17:57:02     126.93289   37.519600
3   location_4  2019-02-26 21:58:27     127.04459   37.524680
4   location_5  2019-02-26 21:58:55      127.02592  37.518500
```

Goal: Loop through each location_i in cu_nodes_df["title"] and compare it's geocode with each geocode in rent_aug_df rows.

this is my code:

```
from haversine import haversine, Unit
data = {}
for node in cu_nodes_df["title"]:

    # (lat, lng) for current cu_node, getting row where title match.
    geo_df = cu_nodes_df.loc[cu_nodes_df["title"] == node][["lng", "lat"]]
    cu_geocode = (geo_df.T.values[0][0], geo_df.T.values[1][0])

    # x = each row of (lat,lng) in rent_aug_df 
    df = pd.DataFrame(rent_aug_df[(rent_aug_df[['lat','lng']].apply(lambda x: haversine(x, cu_geocode), axis=1)) <= 0.1])

    print(df.head())
    print(type(cu_geocode[0]))
    print(cu_geocode)
    print(df.dtypes)

    df.set_index('end_time', inplace = True)
    data[node] = list(df.groupby(df.index.date)["end_loc"].count())

final = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

print outputs:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [end_loc, end_time, lng, lat]
Index: []
<class 'numpy.float64'>
(127.03338, 37.486277)
end_loc             object
end_time    datetime64[ns]
lng                float64
lat                float64
dtype: object
```

I cannot find out what is wrong with the code. I've tried most alternative that I could think of. I've tried on single cu_geocode:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(rent_aug_df[(rent_aug_df[['lat','lng']].apply(lambda x: haversine(x, (37.504855525623, 127.04866656867)), axis=1)) <= 0.1])
```

This works fine, creating df that consisting of rented scooters that were returned within 0.1km boundary

why is it not working inside forloop?
Thanks in advance

EDIT: I have (lng,lat) instead of (lat,lng), when I change it, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Just a tip to code readability.

```
# Augment a new column to have geocode tuple
df['geo_code'] = df.apply(lambda x: (x['lng'], x['lat']))

# Convert to a dict
new_df = df.filter(items['title', 'geo_code'])
data = new_df.to_dict()
```